# How to construct a pyramid in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, shapes

How do I construct a pyramid using a loop program, given a number of rows by a user's input? Such as

```
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

I've tried watching several videos and reading articles about the logic of this, but instructors were either not understandable or they skipped lines of reasoning.

I know every row increases by 2 stars, and I know that because every row has an odd number of stars I can define the number of stars in a row as 2n+1 where n is an integer. I noticed a 2 row triangle has a base of 3 stars, a 3 row triangle has a base of 5 stars, and so on. So for an nth row, the triangles base is n+(n-1), which is 2n-1. For example, r_5: base = 9 stars. The next thing I know my program needs to consider is spacing. I noticed, from the base, spacing increases by 2 every row until we have n-1 spaces on the first half and another n-1 spaces on the second half, in other words, spacing increases from the base until it is greater than or equal to 2b-2.

I think all that covers the gist a java program would need to know: the number of stars per row, the size of the base, and spacing. 
But how do I translate all this in terms of a for while loop?

Comment: Think about this clearly: a for loop will allow the body of the loop to be executed X times, where X is a finite and known number. Think about what in your pyramid is a known and finite number? What is the one thing your program needs to ask the user before it can do its work?

Comment: Just as a note to OP, you're going to need multiple loops. Keep in mind that for loops are used when you know how many iterations you have, whereas while loops are used when the number of iterations is indeterminate. Given these bits and bobs of knowledge and your previous understanding of the algebra, do what Stephen C says and just give it a try. Ignore the posted solutions -- something tells me that you already know you'll get more out of struggling for the answer.

Comment: I've tried coding it myself, but usually I'd just get weird diagonalized stars or a column of stars. Attempting it myself did help to some extent though, it made me realize multiple loops are needed for example. I'm glad I got a lot of responses here though, I'll give it another go when I wake up later today

Answer (score 4):

### Method 1

Note that, if we denote current line number as "line" starting from 0, and total number of lines as "n",

Number of stars in each line = 2*line + 1

Number of leading (or trailing) spaces in each line = n - line - 1

We can simply generate the pyramid using this rule:

```
int n = 4;
for (int line = 0; line < n; line++) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int starsToAppend = 2 * line + 1;
    int spaceToAppend = n - line - 1;

    while (spaceToAppend-- > 0) sb.append(" ");
    while (starsToAppend-- > 0) sb.append("*");

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

---

### Method 2

You can also approach from the middle and expand. Note that there is a constant column of a star (*) in the middle, and on each side, only one star gets added in each line each time. And the rest are spaces.

```
int n = 4;
for(int line=0; line <n ; line++){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("*");
    int spacesToAppendOnBothSides = n-line-1;
    int starsToAppendOnBothSides = line;

    for(int idx=0; idx<starsToAppendOnBothSides; idx++){
        sb.insert(0, "*");  //appends to the beginning
        sb.append("*");     //appends to the end
    }
    for(int idx=0; idx<spacesToAppendOnBothSides; idx++){
        sb.insert(0, " ");
        sb.append(" "); //NOTE: You may exclude this line to avoid adding trailing spaces
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Explanation:

1. On first iteration (line == 0) we take a single star,

```
*
```

2. and add zero extra stars (as our line# is zero) on both sides, which gives us (same string):

```
*
```

3. And then add n-line-1 (we substract 1 because we already added 1 character - the first star) = 3 spaces on each side of that star, which gives us:

```
...*...
```

On 2nd iteration (line == 1) if we apply same logic:
1.

```
    *
```

2. 

```
    ***
     ^ This middle one is the first star
```

3. 

```
    ..***..
```

Pretty simple once you understand the logic.
There are multiple ways to do this, but these are among the simplest ones :)

Answer (score 1):

Say you need to print a pyramid of `n` rows. You can see that row `i` (where `i` is between 1 and `n`) will start with `n-i` spaces and have `(i-1)*2+1` asterisks:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        int spaces = n-i;
        int stars = (i-1)*2+1;
        for (int j = 1; j <= spaces; ++j) {
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= stars; ++j) {
            System.out.print('*');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's my implementation -

```
public static String repeat(String str, int times) {
    return new String(new char[times]).replace("\0", str);
}

public void createPyramid(int size) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i += 2) {
        int numSpaces = (size - i) / 2;
        System.out.println(repeat(" ", numSpaces) + repeat("*", i) + repeat(" ", numSpaces));
    }
}
```

Call the method as - `createPyramid(7);` should give you the desired output. You can increase the size for bigger pyramid.

The variable i iterate for the size of the pyramid. And the number of stars on each row is increasing by 2 starting from 0. There i is incrementing by 2. The blank spaces will be equal to `size - number of *'s` but they have to be repeated before and after the *'s symmetrically, we divide it by 2. This will give the number of spaces before and after the *'s and in the middle we just need to print the *'s whose number is given by i.
So, we finally print them.
The repeat function creates a String formed from the `str` parameter repeated `times` times. eg - if we call `repeat("abc", 3)`, it will return "abcabcabc".